# How can I forward ports 80 and 443 from an external request through Nginx to ports 81 and 444, respectively?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, ip, port

I have docker containers with my own site and I would like to create external ports 444 and 81 from docker and connect it to a user request from my domain from external nginx on my linux machine. How do I organize the nginx.example1.conf file, I created the containers, I just have to connect the ports, how can this be done in the nginx.example1.conf file and am I doing the right thing?

**In short, how do I write the *nginx.example1.conf* file correctly?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as any other reverse proxy configuration for `nginX`, the only difference will be that the endpoints are on `localhost`

This is trivial example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foobar.net www.foobar.net test.io www.test.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For port 443, I do the same and they ssl files will have different links, as I understand it?

Comment: yes, but be cheerful there with the certificates and how do you want to approach the "double ssl" that you will created. My approach is to keep the services always on `http` and use `nginX` to resolve the certificate and expose the `https`, hanse if you want to use this approach you will forward the traffic to port 80 as well.

Comment: Ie, can I remove the certificate in Docker using only http and only use certificates for external Nginx? In this case, will I have to redirect ports 80 and 443 to the same internal port 81?

Comment: Correct, this is what I do for my installations. I expose `80` and `443` on NginX (but usually in a container) and forward traffic to `http` port on the docker container.

Answer (score 1):

First, expose the ports on docker (which means they will be visible and accessible from your host on the same ports)
Then configure your host nginx as a reverse proxy going to localhost:444 and localhost:81 on the / requests